# Running Windows application from Run registry-key causes an error on startup

Tags: windows, registry

I've created a little toy-program, placed it in `C:\tools\Test.exe` and added it to the registry using the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` > `Run` key.

The problem is, that every time the computer starts, I get the "Debug Assertion Failed!" error, and the program doesn't create a file.

The same error occurs if I place the .EXE directly on the C-drive and runs it. However, it doesn't occur when placed in the *tools* folder.

I guess it has something to do with priviledges, but how can I fix this? The registry entry is added manually (not using programming calls).

The programs like iTunesHelper in the `Run` key run just fine, and can be seen using the task manager.

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
    {
        FILE* fh = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
        if (fh != NULL) {
            fprintf(fh, "Hello World!\n");
            fprintf(fh, "Hello World...\n");
            fclose(fh);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Write access to the root of C: requires elevation, add a path to your fopen so you don't attempt to do so.

Comment: Sorry, but I write to the current folder (tools), when I don't provide a path, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I was thinking that when launched via `run` the current directory is not set the same as when run from the shell, adding the full path to fopen will prove/disprove this

Comment: I will try it. Have you experience?

Comment: Your approach did work!